# Simplify validators with Java8

Tags: java, validation, if-statement, functional-programming

I have the following class:

```
public class Client{

    private String name;
    private LocalDate dateOfBirth;
}
```

And currently my validator method looks like:

```
 @Override
    public void validate(Client entity) throws ValidatorException {
        String exceptionMsg="";
        if(entity.getName().isEmpty())
            exceptionMsg+="Client name cannot be empty.";
        LocalDate clientDate = entity.getDateOfBirth();
        LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
        Period difference = Period.between(clientDate, now); //difference between the dates is calculated
        if(difference.getYears() < 18)
            exceptionMsg += "Client must have at least 18 years";

        if(!exceptionMsg.isEmpty())
            throw new ValidatorException(exceptionMsg);

    }
```

How can I replace the ifs from my validation method using Java8 functional programming in order to make my code more readable?

Answer (score 1):

For the String using java 8 functional programming feature, you can use the following :

//to check blank or null string

```
    Predicate<String> isNull = (s) -> (s==null || s.equals(""));
//invoke Lambda
    boolean a=isNull.test(clientName);
```

For date comparison :

```
    Predicate<LocalDate> isLessDifference = (dt) -> ( Period.between( dt,     LocalDate.now()).getYears()<18) ; 
//invoke lambda
    boolean isLess = isLessDifference.test(d2t);
```

I would suggest also go through the following link for more understanding :
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-8-predicate-with-examples/